# Excel, split up comma separated values

Tags: vba, excel, xlsx

I have an Excel sheet with 2 columns.

Column1 contains values like:

> 10969
>   11284
>   1222
>   1227
>   12669
>   12670
>   12671
>   12672

Column2 contains comma separated values like this:

> 601010,6010,40,4010
>   601010,6010,40,4010
>   40,4010,6010,601010
>   40,4010,6010,601010
>   40,4010,6010,601010
>   40,4010,6010,601010
>   40,4010,6010,601010
>   40,4010,6010,601010

I need this split up differently, so instead of having column2 commaseparated, I need 1 row for each value i column 2
Column1 should use the same value for each string, so you get 4 rows with the same number in column1 and different numbers in column2

An example using the data from above

Column1

> 10969
>   10969
>   10969
>   10969
>   11284
>   11284
>   11284
>   11284

Column2

> 601010
>   6010
>   40
>   4010
>   601010
>   6010
>   40
>   4010

It is not the same values everytime, and there is more than 1000 lines, so its a big task to do it manually. 
As far as I can see this is not possible with "standard Excel", But maybe with VBA?

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Regards 
Martin

Comment: have you heard or tried Open XML sdk before :)

Comment: Hi KCdod, no I never heard of that, I will try looking into this and see if this can help solve the problem. 

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that taking a look at this answer will help you a lot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564766/transforming-multiple-entries-in-a-cell-into-multiple-rows

Comment: Hi Petay87, yeah that seems to be my problem exactly. I will look into the different suggetions in that thread. Thanks alot.

Comment: Hi, below formula will convert column in comma separated single cell value e.g 
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A4167)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564766/transforming-multiple-entries-in-a-cell-into-multiple-rows)

I believe the best solution for you would be to run the following VBA while highlighting/Selecting column B:

```
Sub columnsplit()
Dim c As Range
Dim splitv() As String

For Each c In Selection
    splitv = Split(c.Value, ",")
    If UBound(splitv) > 0 Then
        c.EntireRow.Insert
        c.Offset(-1, 0).Value = splitv(1)
        c.Offset(-1, -1).Value = c.Offset(0, -1).Value
        c.Value = splitv(0)
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

This should give you desired result.

However, when I tested the code, it was sometimes not clear if the code had ran as you need to remember that Excel has a nice feature of adding commas for you to separate numerical values.

For example, where you might have 123456,123456789 this code will split it but Excel might then display 123,456 and 123,456,789 as the results. You will need to amend your formatting so that this does not happen.

Comment: Hi Petay87, I also had some problems with that vba script, so I instead used the other one from NickSlash, and that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect fit for Power Query. Suck the table into Power Query, split Column2 with the comma delimiter, select all but the first columns and click Unpivot.

One of the major processing problems is that numeric data is separated with a comma, and a comma can also be a "thousand" separator in large numbers. I've tried to copy your data sample, but some rows come back as text with only numbers and commas, and other rows come back as very, very big numbers in exponential format.

So you may need to do some work on defining the incoming data type. This may be an issue with regional settings. My regional settings have the comma as the thousand delimiter.

You may be better off posting an actual Excel file with a file sharing service and post a link here.

Power Query can do this -- that's a given. We just need to straighten out the data format to work out HOW to do it.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, thanks for your answer. Im not familiar with Power Query but it sounds interesting. 

As written to Petay87 answer, I found the solution in the other stackoverflow thread, which solved my problem.