# Create dropdown list from comma separated values when workbook open

Tags: vba, excel

I have one column has comma separated values populating from DB. The Range could be anything.

[image]

When open the workbook that comma separated column should be dropdown with values using vba.

I am very new to this macro. I have written the below code. its working fine for single cell. But, I want to do this for certain range like example "H" Column from H1 to last. How to achieve this? Can help me?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    AddListValidation "Task", "A1", "A2"
End Sub


Sub AddListValidation(sheet, cellSource As Range, cellTarget As Range)
    Dim Lastrow As Integer
    Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    txt = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cellSource).Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cellTarget) = "Select your values here"
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cellTarget).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="xxx,yyy,zzz"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Well what exactly is your question, you didn't ask one? This is not a free code writing service. You will need to start on your own and then if you get stuck show the code you already have and ask a question to it.

Comment: I know this s not a free code service.  Problem in my system. Was trying to edit my post.

Comment: What you want to do is `split` the values in the first column. It is possible to do so, [without vba](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-functions-49ec57f9-3d5a-44b2-82da-50dded6e4a68). I think you may find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564766/transforming-multiple-entries-in-a-cell-into-multiple-rows) usefull to integrate into your generated code

Answer (score 1):

You will need a loop to call `AddListValidation` for every row. Also you don't need a parameter for the worksheet when you give full qualified ranges as parameters instead of addresses.

It is recommended [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA there is no benefit in using `Integer` at all. Especially for row counts because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle4")

    Dim LastRow As Long 'always use long instead of integer
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To LastRow
        AddListValidation ws.Cells(iRow, "A"), ws.Cells(iRow, "B")
    Next iRow
End Sub


Sub AddListValidation(cellSource As Range, cellTarget As Range)
    cellTarget.Value = "Select your values here"
    With cellTarget.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=cellSource.Value
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ya , its working fine. but when i did some changes and closed the excel. And if i try to open the same, its repairing that excel and that sheet moved to the next sheet. Dropdown values also not coming.

Comment: Well, repairing means that probably your Excel file is corrupt. That has nothing to do with the code. Try to make a new workbook and copy/past everything into to new workbook. OR try to save it in the binary XLSB format (which often is more stable).

Comment: no, it has totally 8 sheets. each one has different functionality. Actually , there are some other columns also dropdown in this sheet. but, now i commented this set of code and did the save and opened again. its working as expected.

Comment: And am doing it in WorkSheet_Activate().

Comment: "*Will it cause of pbm?*" What? I don't understand you, sorry.

Comment: am creating the dropdown list when activate the worksheet not when opening it. Is it fine?

Comment: Well, If it works for you. Yes. If this solved your question please mark this answer as solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168850/discussion-between-aaroki-and-p).